# Popular Post With Thumbnail?

Tags: plugins

Is there any plugin that allows you to use a custom field as the thumbnail to display the most popular post within the last day (24 hours)?

I have found several plugins but none seem to have the capabilities that would allow me to add a custom field as the image or even a thumbnail at all.

Comment: i would like to know also.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the $Post->ID of the "most popular post", why not just use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)):

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, $size ); ?>
```

Comment: I don't know the post id since it would change daily. I would like a plugin that tracks daily views that can display a thumbnail on the sidebar. I hate widgets and don't use them so I need something I can call for in the sidebar. Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest using (or hacking) one of the existing "Popular Posts" Plugins, rather than re-inventing the wheel.